# Can we use jquery $.post() for using muliple urls in it

Tags: jquery, json

```
        var js={"studentId":$(this).val()};
        $.post(url+"admin/course/getformadmissionfees",js,function(data){
        $("#student").val(data.admissionFee);
        $("#studentform").val(data.formFee);
```

My question can i include different url 1

> url+"admin/course/getformadmissionfees"

and url 2

url+"admin/course/getformadmissionfees"

> url+"admin/course/getformadmission"

in one $.post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. It is only one HTTP call. You can however roll this up into reusable bites.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't, because each `$.post` handles only one request.

You can, however, design your server-side script to accept more parameters, eg:
`admin/course/getformadmission/getformadmissionfees`